# Find the best constant $k$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}}{\sqrt{a+b+c+k\cdot abc}}\le 1+\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, radicals

**Problem.** Find the minimal $k$ value such that $$\frac{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}}{\sqrt{a+b+c+k\cdot abc}}\le 1+\sqrt{2}$$ holds for all $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.$

I'm not sure my prediction is correct 100%. Hope you can point out my mistakes.

By plugging $a=b=c=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},$ we get $k\ge 153-108\sqrt{2}:= k_0.$

Now, we'll prove $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\le (1+\sqrt{2}) \sqrt{a+b+c+k_0\cdot abc}.$$

It means that $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\le (1+\sqrt{2}) \sqrt{a+b+c+k_0\cdot \frac{abc}{ab+bc+ca}}.$$
I thought of squaring both side of the last inequality but nothing interesting left.

I hope that my $k_0$ is right answer. In case it's true, you can share your idea and comment how to full th remain part.

Thanks for interest.

Answer (score 2):

**Some thoughts.**

*Remark*: It is similar to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796969/finding-small-max-limits-abbcca-1-dfrac-sqrtabc-sqrtbca-sqrtca/4798454#4798454).

It suffices to prove that
$$(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a})^2 \le (3 + 2\sqrt 2)(a + b + c + k_0abc). \tag{1}$$

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a})^2\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + b}{\frac12a + \frac12b+ \frac{3 - 2\sqrt{2}}{2}c(a + b) - (3 - 2\sqrt{2})ab + \frac13k_0 abc}\right) \\[6pt]
 &\qquad \times \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac12a + \frac12b+ \frac{3 - 2\sqrt{2}}{2}c(a + b) - (3 - 2\sqrt{2})ab + \frac13k_0 abc\right)\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + b}{\frac12a + \frac12b+ \frac{3 - 2\sqrt{2}}{2}c(a + b) - (3 - 2\sqrt{2})ab + \frac13k_0 abc}\right) (a + b + c + k_0abc).
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + b}{\frac12a + \frac12b+ \frac{3 - 2\sqrt{2}}{2}c(a + b) - (3 - 2\sqrt{2})ab + \frac13k_0 abc}
\le 3 + 2\sqrt{2}. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true which is verified by *Mathematica* - a Computer Algebra System (CAS). I think we can use the pqr method.

Comment: I checked your idea. It's true. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anonymous You are welcome.